# How to extend a Joi schema?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, joi

I have a joi schema called user

```
const user = {
  firstName: Joi.string()
    .min(2)
    .max(50)
    .required()
    .label('First Name'),
  lastName: Joi.string()
    .min(3)
    .max(50)
    .required()
    .label('Last Name'),
  email: Joi.string()
    .allow('')
    .email({ minDomainAtoms: 2 })
    .max(100)
    .label('Email Address'),
}
```

I had another one called owner

```
const ownerSchema = {
  firstName: Joi.string()
    .min(2)
    .max(50)
    .required()
    .label('First Name'),
  lastName: Joi.string()
    .min(3)
    .max(50)
    .required()
    .label('Last Name'),
  email: Joi.string()
    .allow('')
    .email({ minDomainAtoms: 2 })
    .max(100)
    .label('Email Address'),
  number: Joi.string()
    .regex(/[0-9]/)
    .length(10)
    .required()
    .label('Phone Number'),
  dateOfBirth: Joi.date(),

  kycDetails: Joi.array()
    .items(schemaKyc)
    .required(),
  bankDetails: Joi.array()
    .items(schemaBank)
    .required(),
  licenceDetails: Joi.array()
    .items(schemaLicence)
    .required(),
  insuranceDetails: Joi.array()
    .items(schemaInsurance)
    .required()
};
```

As you can see the both have three fields in common I want to be able to use the user schema in owner and whenever I make changes to the user I want it to reflect in the owner as well.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use [`object.keys([schema])`](https://joi.dev/api/#objectkeysschema), which

> Sets or extends the allowed object keys where:

> - `schema` - optional object where each key is assigned a **joi** type object.
>   If `schema` is `{}` no keys allowed. If `schema` is `null` or `undefined`, any
>   key allowed. If `schema` is an object with keys, the keys are added to
>   any previously defined keys (but narrows the selection if all keys
>   previously allowed). Defaults to 'undefined' which allows any child
>   key.

Example:

```
const base = Joi.object().keys({
    a: Joi.number(),
    b: Joi.string()
});
// Validate keys a, b and c.
const extended = base.keys({
    c: Joi.boolean()
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Simply you can [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) the `user` inside `ownerSchema`:

```
const ownerSchema = {
    ...user,
    /* owner specific fields goes here */
};
```

Comment: an example to understand?

Answer (score 7):

I use `append` as written in the docs

```
// Validate keys a, b
const base = Joi.object({
    a: Joi.number(),
    b: Joi.string()
});
// Validate keys a, b, c
const extended = base.append({
    c: Joi.string()
});
```

Comment: Additional: This is also works to overwrite existing props rules