# Extend two JOI validation base schemas

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

I'm using an extension of `baseValidationSchema` for many of my schemas.

Now, inside a schema named `contactSchema` which contains many address related keys which I want to be using `baseAddressSchema`.

I tried to spread it as suggested in [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57248815/14315323):

```
export const contactSchema = baseValidationSchema.keys({
  ...baseAddressSchema,
  email: validateEmail(),
  firstName: validateName(),
  lastName: validateName(),
  phone: validatePhone(),
  spamFlag: validateBoolean()
});
```

But it throws an error:

> Error: Schema can only contain plain objects

How should I do it right?

Comment: Can you show the `baseAddressSchema`?